# React DOM change component on window resize

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I need to change the logo when window width small than 768 but can't realize it.
Must be responsive on window width changes. 
what is wrong with my code? 
thank you!

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            winWidth: 0
        };
        this.getWindowSize = this.getWindowSize.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWindowSize();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowSize);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getWindowSize);
      }

      getWindowSize() {
        this.setState({ winWidth: window.innerWidth});
      }

    changeLogo(logo){
        if(this.state.winWidth < 768){
            logo = './images/small.png';

        }
        logo = './images/regular.png';   
    }


    render() {
        const {logo} = this.props;
        return (
               <div className="Header">
                 <img src={ this.changeLogo(logo) } alt="logo"/>
            </div> 
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try to use CSS instead of JS** to show different images based on the screen width.

```
<Header class="Header">
    <img src="./images/small.png" className="small-screen-logo" alt="logo"/>
    <img src="./images/regular.png" className="large-screen-logo" alt="logo"/>
</Header>
```

Display a small screen logo, if the screen size is more than 768px display the bigger screen logo

```
.small-screen-logo {
    display: block;
}

.large-screen-logo {
    display: none;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .small-screen-logo {
        display: none;
    }

    .large-screen-logo {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

If you use bootstrap you can achieve it with bootstrap classes:

```
<Header class="Header">
    <img src="./images/small.png" className="d-block d-md-none" alt="logo"/>
    <img src="./images/regular.png" className="d-none d-md-block" alt="logo"/>
</Header>
```

Suggested reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries

**In case you want to use JS** you can add a method `logo` instead of `changeLogo(logo)`.

```
logo() {
    return './images/' + (this.state.winWidth < 768 ? 'small.png' : 'regular.png') + '.png';
}
```

Then use it in render as following:

```
<img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is an alternative way but what if I need to realize it by react component with jsx

Comment: that's perfect 

Answer (score 2):

Use srcset in image tag to specify different src for different screen size:

```html
<img srcset="https://placekitten.com/768/768 768w,
             https://placekitten.com/1366/1366 1366w"
     sizes="(max-width: 768px) 768px,
            1366px"
     src="https://placekitten.com/1366/1366" alt="placeholder kitten">
```

Use `srcset` to declare multiple sources of image, `sizes` to define which src is to be used in which condition.

Link to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) for further reading.